# Add Facebook Pixel to Vue project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, facebook-pixel

I am trying to implement Facebook pixel in a Vue project, but I can't seem to figure out where to implement it. I created a `.js` file with the fb code. 
I think I am supposed to be calling it in vue.config.js (I saw that in an example where the user also used Nuxt (which I am not using). I added it like this
script: 
`{ src: 'external.js', type: 'text/javascript' })`

but it is not working and I really need some help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is how I implements it for my Vue/Angular/React projects.

Normally the FB pixel code consist of 2 part

1. the initializing code

e.g.

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
  !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
  {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
  n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
  if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
  n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
  t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
  'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
  fbq('init', 'YOUR_APP_ID');
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
  src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=YOUR_APP_ID&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

2. the tracking function

like `fbq('trackCustom', 'SOME_PAGE_NAME');`

What works for me is to put the initializing code in the `index.html` in src.

And put the tracking function to where it should be. for e.g. if it's tracking signup, I put `fbq('trackCustom', 'signup');` in the function after signup is successful.

Similar concepts can be applied to Google Analytics as well.

Comment: When i try to put that inside .vue file its saying 
fbq is not defined
Any idea?

Comment: @ShujatMunawar you have to use something like, window.fbq('trackCustom', 'signup'), ie window.fbq

Comment: In vue, the pixel is getting called in all the pages till reload, followed the exact same method as mentioned by @Jacob